# Find out all the Queries listening on a Meteor.js Collection

Tags: meteor

In Meteor 0.7.0.1, is it possible to count/find out the all the queries that are currently listening to a particular Collection?

I am trying to create a function which does: Whenever the number of users listening on a particular query (eg: `myCollection.find({color:'red'})` becomes non-zero, execute a function whenever documents are changed/added to a second Collection `anotherCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

When/how is the find method called? If it's called when someone hits a button on the page, for instance, simply increase a serverside variable that will increase when that happens. To decrease this variable when the user leaves the page, listen to the `window.onbeforeunload` event and decrease the count when it happens.

Alternately, if you have a login system, assign a boolean value such as `online` to each user. When they log in, make their online status true with the following code. `if(Meteor.user()){Meteor.user().online=true;}`. Make sure an `onbeforeunload` sets their online status to false when they leave. Then, do something like `Meteor.users.find({online:true}).size()` to get the amount of users online.

Basically, rather than update when `myCollection.find({color:'red'})` is called, put that in a function. For instance:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
Session.set('browsing', false);
function findColor(c){//Alerts the server when the user attempts to get a color. 
//This is presuming they don't use the plain MongoDB command. 
//Your button/however you're finding the color should use this command
if(!Session.get('browsing'))//if it's already true, don't increase the count
{
Meteor.call('incBrowsing');
Session.set('browsing', true);
}

return myCollection.find({color:c});
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(){Meteor.call('decBrowsing');};
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
var browsing = 0;
Meteor.methods({
incBrowsing: function(){browsing++;},
decBrowsing: function(){browsing++;}
});
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I hope it works for you. You didn't provide too many details on your problem, so feel free to comment below if you or I need to clarify something.

Comment: Thank you for your response! For detecting whether the user is still on the page, is there something more reliable than `window.onbeforeunload`? Is there something to detect whether the websocket connection is still active?

Comment: You can definitely use websockets, but it'd be considerably more complex than a built in window event. Meteor uses SockJS, if you'd like to look into that.